# Criar um filtro em Angular com smart table

Tags: angularjs, angular

estou começando agora com Angular, e não tenho muito conhecimento, gostaria de saber se alguém que tenha mais conhecimento pode me ajudar a fazer um filtro em Angular com Smart Table.

Ex:  Tenho uma caixa de texto que irá recuperar de uma lista de itens os itens que correspondam ao valor do que for posto na caixa.
No meu caso eu quero inserir uma letra,
e retornar todos os itens que começam com aquela letra.
Por favor me dêem um help

Comment: Por favor poste um código do que vc tentou, ninguém aqui vai fazer tudo pra vc.

Comment: @san Nunes: https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/examples/using-filters

Answer (score 0):

Tente pesquisar na API do Angular que tem muitos exemplos,

mais existem exemplos como:
https://jsfiddle.net/jasmin_kurtic/yat6ghjx/

caso angular1

NamePhone
  
    {{friendObj.name}}
    {{friendObj.phone}}

Voce pode filtrar utilizando ng-repeat e angular2 pode utilizar *ngFor

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 0):

Isso também pode te ajudar
Voce consegue debugar o codigo com esse exemplo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-ng2-smart-table